# Issue with Locking screen widget setting

Tags: android

I am developing an application of display my application on locking screen widget area so i have find some example from [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html) and i have tried to make services which handle by `AppWidgetProvider` class but when I am run it on emulator its not display my application on locking screen.
here is my activity..

```
ExampleAppWidgetProvider asd = new ExampleAppWidgetProvider();
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager= AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        int[] appWidgetIds = null;
        asd.onUpdate(getApplicationContext(), appWidgetManager,appWidgetIds);
```

**ExampleAppWidgetProvider**

```
private static final String LOG = "de.vogella.android.widget.example";

      @Override
      public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
          int[] appWidgetIds) {

        Log.w(LOG, "onUpdate method called");
        // Get all ids
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
                ExampleAppWidgetProvider.class);
        int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

        // Build the intent to call the service
        Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
            UpdateWidgetService.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);

        // Update the widgets via the service
        context.startService(intent);
      }
```

**UpdateWidgetService**

```
public class UpdateWidgetService extends Service {
    private static final String LOG = "de.vogella.android.widget.example";

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Log.i(LOG, "Called");
        // Create some random data

        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this
                .getApplicationContext());

        int[] allWidgetIds = intent
                .getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);

        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),
                ExampleAppWidgetProvider.class);
        int[] allWidgetIds2 = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
        Log.w(LOG, "From Intent" + String.valueOf(allWidgetIds.length));
        Log.w(LOG, "Direct" + String.valueOf(allWidgetIds2.length));

        for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
            // Create some random data
            int number = (new Random().nextInt(100));

            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this
                    .getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget1);
            Log.w("WidgetExample", String.valueOf(number));
            // Set the text
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.app_name,
                    "Random: " + String.valueOf(number));

            // Register an onClickListener
            Intent clickIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),
                    ExampleAppWidgetProvider.class);

            clickIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
            clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,
                    allWidgetIds);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    getApplicationContext(), 0, clickIntent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.movie_name, pendingIntent);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
        }
        stopSelf();

        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my answer on a similar question:

- [How to create a custom lock screen widget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23697807/383414)

There are 2 changes to make it work as a lock-screen widget:

- updating the `widgetCategory` to include `keyguard`
- adding an `initialKeyguardLayout`

These changes are done in the `./res/xml/widget_info.xml` file, as seen below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard" >
</appwidget-provider>
```

Have a look at that other answer - it contains links to a very simple demo widget that you can get from my github. They may help you, even though they do not relate exactly to this question.