# How to create a custom lock screen widget (I just want to display a button)

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to allow users to quickly capture an image using my app when the device is locked.  I figure the quickest way for a user to do this is via a button/widget on the lock screen - although I'm not sure how to build this.

Most references I've found have related to music playback and use of the RemoteControlClient (which may be just Android 4.4?).  At it's most basic I'd just like one button that said "capture".  Any help on how to do this?

Comment: I followed my advice that I gave you yesterday, and I have updated my simple widget demo to work on the lock-screen. It is (luckily) as easy as I said it was. Hopefully the answer below will help.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier thanks for your answer Richard.  In my specific usecase I have realised I cannot do what I want - I needed a lock screen widiget to allow users with encrypted devices to quickly take photos without having to enter long passwords.  I have done some reading and it seems like some phones support lockscreens widigets while encrypted whereas others dont (such as the Samsung Galaxy S4), here's a [link](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s4/272475-lock-screen-widgets-security-pin-enabled.html) for anyone intersted in the issue.

Comment: Yes, I realised your usecase would probably not work, but thought the question would benefit from this type of explanation anyway. Good luck with that project.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### API Levels

Lock-screen widgets were introduced in API 17 (4.2), and removed in API 21 (5.0). They are not supported on other official releases.

---

### Basic Widget

I wrote a simple widget as a demo tutorial - it contains all the boilerplate code required for a widget, and very little else:

- [WiFi Widget Demo (github)](https://github.com/mobiRic/WifiWidget)
- [WiFi Widget (Play store)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobiric.demo.wifiwidget)

I wrote it in such a way to make it easy for anyone to remove the "wifi" related code, and adapt it to their own widget requirements. It might be perfect for you to look at, and relatively simple to add a single button to it.

---

### Lock-screen / Keyguard Widget

There are 2 changes to make it work as a lock-screen widget:

- updating the `widgetCategory` to include `keyguard`
- adding an `initialKeyguardLayout`

These changes are done in the `./res/xml/widget_info.xml` file, as seen below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:minWidth="250dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="0"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard" >
</appwidget-provider>
```

---

I do not know if it is possible to integrate the camera into your own lock-screen widget. Clicking on a lock-screen widget normally requires the user to unlock the device before the click works.

Comment: sorry i updating the widgetCategory to include keyguard. But no thing display in lock screen. I use genymotion android 4.2.2