# How do i make my android app accessible from the lockscreen?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an app to be  used during emergencies and it's important that the app can be started from the lockscreen. Is this possible(it seems to be posssible, since i see apps like this on the Google Playstore) and how would i achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682910/how-to-create-a-custom-lock-screen-widget-i-just-want-to-display-a-button check this question

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off replacing the lock screen. You'll have more control and be able to provide a better user experience. Downside is you have a lot of code to write.

See this: 
[Creating an Android Lock Screen App.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943407/creating-an-android-lock-screen-app)

Answer (score 1):

Making a lock screen widget was possible in between android 4.4.2 until android lollipop. All other version do not have this ability. As such the best alternative would be for your app to replace the built in launcher and create its own lockscreen which you would be able to customize yourself.